# May I use 'to injure' in a figurative way?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is the phrase

*This behaviour injures our project*

a legitimate substitute for

*This behavior is harmful to our project*

or is it only possible to use 'to injure'  for damaging a living body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use injure for non-living things. For example, *"The scandal injured the company's reputation."* or *"Showing up late often could injure your chances for a promotion."*

After thinking about it, I wanted to mention that I would typically use "hurt" or "damage" instead of "injure". In my examples, I would say "damaged the reputation" and "hurt your chances" probably because that is what I hear used most often.